# Can not use CGPoint to set the position in Swift with Sprite Kit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I don't seem to be able to set the position of my node in sprite kit using swift:

```
let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Spaceship")
let point: CGPoint = CGPoint(x:10,y:10)
sprite.position = point
self.addChild(sprite)
```

It works when I do:

```
sprite.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there an error or what happens?

Comment: @ChristianWoerz No, the node just never get created...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you problem is, that you just don't see the node. It gets created, but at a point where you don't see it. To change that, open your `GameViewController` file and add the following line before `skView.presentScene(scene)`:

```
scene.size = skView.bounds.size
```

That code will make sure that the size of your scene is the same size as the size of your screen. So now you should be able to see the node.

Comment: I thought the scene was always the size of the screen :) I guess will have to read further. Thanks!